# PHP out of memory error

Tags: php, centos7

I am running PHP 5.4.16 with Zend Engine v2.4.0 on Centos 7.8.2003. When the server boots up I get strange php memory problems. So, I set memory limit to unlimited in php.ini and now I am getting out of memory errors. The problem goes away after I restart httpd, but happens again after a reboot of the server. What might be causing this?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 524288) (tried to allocate 18446744073626105608 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Well, that magic number is a huge clue that there's a bug somewhere. Can't you update to a current PHP version?!

Comment: I have not actually considered that there might be a bug in the php itself. I will try after updating.

Comment: Unfortunately, the client uses an application that is encoded for ioncube 5.4 so I cannot upgrade the php...